# PHP VK SDK - не получается авторизоваться

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, php-vksdk

Уже который час не могу выполнить авторизацию сообщества. Делаю это с помощью нового VK SDK:

```
<?php
require ('vendor/autoload.php');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: root
 * Date: 27.04.18
 * Time: 11:31
 */

use VK\{
    Client\VKApiClient, Exceptions\VKClientException, Exceptions\VKOAuthException, OAuth\Scopes\VKOAuthGroupScope, OAuth\VKOAuth, OAuth\VKOAuthDisplay, OAuth\VKOAuthResponseType
};


$vk = new VKApiClient();
$oauth = new VKOAuth();
$client_id = %id приложения%;
$redirect_uri = 'localhost/provzn_cover';
$display = VKOAuthDisplay::POPUP;
$scope = [VKOAuthGroupScope::MANAGE];
$groups_ids = [%id групп%];
$client_secret = %секретный ключ%;

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $browser_url = $oauth->getAuthorizeUrl(VKOAuthResponseType::CODE, $client_id, $redirect_uri, $display, $scope, null, $groups_ids);
    header('Location:'.$browser_url);
} else {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    try {
        $response = $oauth->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri, $code);
    } catch (VKClientException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    } catch (VKOAuthException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    $access_token = $response['access_token'];
}
```

Мне выводит следующую ошибку:

```
Invalid http status: 401
```

Если вручную перейти по сформированному URL, то показывается следующее:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Code is invalid or expired."
}
```

Нигде не могу найти информацию об этой ошибке и о том, как её исправить. Кто может помочь?

Comment: 401 - нет авторизации

Answer (score 3):

```
$redirect_uri = 'localhost/provzn_cover';
```

С локальными не работает, адрес нужно полностью указать, если адрес есть.

Вот пример

```
$redirect_uri = 'https://mysite.ru/login.php';
```